# A short story collection that featured an excerpt from the novelization of Star Wars by George Lucas/Alan Dean Foster

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, short-stories

In my childhood I was gifted a hardcover sci-fi short story anthology that featured an excerpt from the novelization of Star Wars by George Lucas/Alan Dean Foster. As I recall, it was from their time on the Death Star, and it was illustrated with sketches that were either drawn a) by someone who'd never seen the movie or b) by someone really careful to avoid recreating the movie designs for legal reasons. I mention that the book was hardcover, but as I recall the dark cover was oddly glossy.

Does anyone know what this collection was called? Does anyone know where I can find a list of collections that were authorized to excerpt the novelization?

Comment: @Dan: Please update your question with more information: What does "e" mean (I assume something is missing)? Ca. what year did you get the anthology? Was it new then? Did you read it in English or another language? Do you remember anything about the cover other than it was dark? Or any other stories from the book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1983 anthology "[Beyond the Stars](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4403)" contained *[Escape from the Death Star](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?877671)*, an excerpt from the ghostwritten novel. As far as isfdb.org knows, the excerpt has not appeared anywhere else.

[image]

The book featured some wonderful illustrations of each story by Peter Dennis.
[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the illustrations. They're rather good for someone who's clearly only seen the excerpt and some of the concept art

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe how quickly Organic Marble found the answer!

Comment: @Dan you're most welcome, and thanks for the accept.